# Android: Hide viewPager tabs when launching a fragment from one of the viewPager tab fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a viewPager in my app which has several tabs. In some of the tabs, on clicking an item a new fragment is shown. I want this fragment to cover the tabs. Doing this is possible but the approaches don't look good to me.

1.) one way is that I add the newly created fragment to the activity using `getSupportFragmentManager()`. This solves the problem but doesn't look like a good idea as it will create problems when using back button etc.

2.) Other way is to hide the tabs manually using `Visibilty.GONE` but problem with this approach is that this hiding of the tabs is visible, I mean the animation could be seen and looks bad.

Is there a better approach to do this problem?

This is my code. "`sub_fragment_container`" is present in the activity xml, so I get an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e00ff (com.my.app:id/sub_fragment_container) for fragment DetailFragment{`

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                Fragment profileFragment = new DetailFragment();
                profileFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction
                        .add(R.id.sub_fragment_container, profileFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`

Or, to fine tune it further, here's a tested method that I've personally used in my app [Newslet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grafixartist.newslet) to solve the exact same problem.

1. Wrap your Toolbar and TabLayout within an AppBarLayout. This should be easy if you're aware of the Design Support Library. If not, [this](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/) should get you started.
2. Add this piece of code in your onCreate():

   ```
   LayoutTransition layoutTransition = new LayoutTransition();
   layoutTransition.setDuration(200);
   layoutTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_APPEARING, 0);
   layoutTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, 0);
   layoutTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, 0);
   layoutTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING, 0);

   appBarLayout.setLayoutTransition(layoutTransition);
   ```

After this, when you remove the Tabs or add it back, the layout change will animate smoothly.

Hope this helped you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to reply. I will try it and accept if it works !!